# Rotating arc around center in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have an arc instantiated like this:

```
Var arc = new createjs.Shape();
arc.graphics.beginStroke('#6d6e71')
                .setStrokeStyle(16)
                .arc(CONSTANTS.WIDTH/2, CONSTANTS.HEIGHT/2, 250, 0 + doorPosition, Math.PI/5 + doorPosition);
```

And I want to rotate it around the center as if the rest of the arc were completed. It seems to rotate around the 0,0 point if the circle were contained in a rectangle when using setTransform:

```
arc.setTransform(0, 0, 1, 1, angle);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation is around the (0,0) point because even if your arc is drawn at (CONSTANTS.WIDTH/2, CONSTANTS.HEIGHT/2), your shape position is still (0,0). Instead, place your shape before :

```
var arc = new createjs.Shape();
arc.x = CONSTANTS.WIDTH/2;
arc.y = CONSTANTS.HEIGHT/2;
arc.graphics.beginStroke('#6d6e71')
            .setStrokeStyle(16)
            .arc(0,0, 250, 0 + doorPosition, Math.PI/5  + doorPosition);
```

And if you just want to rotate your arc, you can just modify the "rotation" property instead of using "setTransform" :

```
arc.rotation = angle;
```

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/JTqvJ/40/, hope this helps.